# How do I copy a function to a new symbol?

Tags: scheme, lisp, common-lisp, first-class-functions

I've got a question regarding the copy of function in Common Lisp.

In Scheme I'd go with:

```
(define (foo par1 par2) (+ par1 par2))
(define bar foo)
(print (bar 1 2)) ;; --> prints 3
(define (foo par1 par2) (* par1 par2))
(print (bar 1 2)) ;; --> prints again 3
(print (foo 1 2)) ;; --> prints 2
```

How can i do this with Common Lisp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the differences between Scheme and Common Lisp is, that **Common Lisp has separate namespaces for functions and values**. In Scheme we can set the value - that's also all that is there. In Common Lisp we need to set the function and not the value, if we want to set or change the function of a symbol.

`SYMBOL-FUNCTION` gives you the function for a symbol. You can use the function `(setf symbol-function)` to set the function of a symbol. See below for an example:

```
CL-USER 50 > (defun foo (par1 par2) (+ par1 par2))
FOO

CL-USER 51 > (setf (symbol-function 'bar) (symbol-function 'foo))
#<interpreted function FOO 4060000C3C>

CL-USER 52 > (bar 1 2)
3

CL-USER 53 > (defun foo (par1 par2) (* par1 par2))
FOO

CL-USER 54 > (bar 1 2)
3

CL-USER 55 > (foo 1 2)
2
```

Comment: Thank you, i figured i have to somehow write the function to the symbol however I had no clue how to do that.

Comment: You can also (setf bar (symbol-function 'foo)) - but then to invoke you would have to go (**funcall** bar 1 2).